# Have problem with the "give" command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

It's that command:

```
/give @p diamond_block 1 0 {display:{Name:"Extreme Route #1 Prize"},ench:[{id:20,lvl:27},{id:16,lvl:2727}],HideFlags:127}
```

And I want to add `{CanPlaceOn:["quartz_stairs"]}`.

But the command block is saying: `Data tag parsing failed: Trailing data found at:
...},{id:16,lvl:2727}],HideFlags:127},<--[HERE]`

The command works perfectly without the "can place on". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't actually put the problematic command in. Please do that, otherwise the answer will just be "add it after a comma".

Comment: You probably added the extra `{ }` to your command while `CanPlaceOn:[]` belongs in the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

The command you need is:

```
/give @p diamond_block 1 0 {display:{Name:"Extreme Route #1 Prize"},ench:[{id:20,lvl:27},{id:16,lvl:2727}],HideFlags:127,CanPlaceOn:["quartz_stairs"]}
```

(assuming both parts of your given command are correct in themselves, I didn't check that)

Since you didn't provide the problematic command, I can't tell you more about your problem. The error message looks like you had a closing bracket too much or maybe at the wrong position, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the information outside of the data tag list.

Lets simplify the data portion of your original command and add a bunch of extra spaces for visual clarity:

```
{  display:{...}, ench:[...], HideFlags:127  }
```

A list with three items in it.  When you added `CanPlaceOn`, you added it outside of that list like this:

```
{display:{...},ench:[...],HideFlags:127},   {CanPlaceOn:[...]}
```

This is why the error mentions trailing data.  It noticed the list was done and there was extra stuff after the list.  You want to add that `CanPlaceOn` inside the list as another list item like this:

```
{  display:{...}, ench:[...], HideFlags:127, CanPlaceOn:[...]  }
```

Now it is part of the list which makes up the data tag.  A list with 4 items.  Here is the correct command:

```
/give @p diamond_block 1 0 {display:{Name:"Extreme Route #1 Prize"},ench:[{id:20,lvl:27},{id:16,lvl:2727}],HideFlags:127,CanPlaceOn:["quartz_stairs"]}
```

Which gives us:
[image: Diamond]

Without the hideflags:
[image: Without Flags]